# Qt Creator - errors when header for a dll appears in more than one place

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt-creator

I have a bizarre problem using Qt Creator that I can't reproduce with Visual Studio. 
For the project I'm working with I have to use a third party dll, and to that end I need to include in the code also an appropriate header file. However, even though the header file has a set of

```
#ifndef VICON
#define VICON

//...

#endif  // VICON
```

guards, as soon as I include the header in more than one source code file (either directly or indirectly), I get following linking errors:

1. mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl ViconDataStreamSDK::CPP::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class ViconDataStreamSDK::CPP::String const &)" (??6CPP@ViconDataStreamSDK@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV23@ABVString@01@@Z) already defined in main.obj
2. debug\Beetle_01.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I can provide you with the source code, but that seems to be irrelevant, even if I'm not calling anything from this DLL, as soon as the related header file appears in more than one place I get above errors. No issues if the header file is only in one place, I can then call its content and everything works as expected.

Here's how I include the dll in the .pro file, hope it's the right way:

```
INCLUDEPATH += .
win32:LIBS += ViconDataStreamSDK_CPP.lib
```

(And relevant lib, dll, and h files are all in the current dir)
I'm coding on Windows 7, btw.

Comment: @Joachihim - very quickly - this seems to work. I found an operator<< function in the .h file, preapprended it with inline, and things seems fine now. I don't want to be too hasty, but please assume problem solved until I come crying again :)

As a side note - any idea why Visual Studio didn't have problems with it then?

Comment: @Joachim: Could you make a solution from this: it looks as though the problem and the answer are general enough to be interesting for future readers!

Comment: *one or more multiply defined symbols found* - it's clear what the problem is, isn't it?

Comment: @VJovic - it wasn't to me, I thought it means a problem with the file as a whole, most likely with how I included it, and not with some small portion of the header. Will hopefully be a bit wiser the next time round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the library might define the `operator<<` function in a header file, but forgot to mark it as `static` or `inline`. This means it will be defined in all source files including the header file, and you will get the linker error you describe.

Comment: Why static? It should be only `inline`. A function in a header shouldn't be static.